# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Chemistry Stack Exchange](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Too much homework :/ I may post a longer answer on this later, but I'm a bit caught up IRL this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Increase in bond length of BF₄⁻ compared to BF₃](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6293/increase-in-bond-length-of-bf4-compared-to-bf3)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Nuclear fusion reactions violate law of conservation of mass, but it has not yet been taken into account. Why?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/nuclear-fusion-reactions-violate-law-of-conservation-of-mass-but-it-has-not-yet)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Choosing the best reagent](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/choosing-the-best-reagent)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to calculate if a given solution of MgCl₂ is saturated?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6264/stranded-in-this-solutions-question)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why do only chiral molecules rotate the plane of polarized light and how do they rotate it?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6439/why-only-chiral-molecules-rotate-plane-polarized-light-and-how-does-it-rotate-li)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to properly work with potassium HMDS](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6340/how-to-properly-work-with-potassium-hmds)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Calculating the pH of a solution of Ca(OH)2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6216/calculating-the-ph-of-a-solution-of-caoh2)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Finding the number of orbitals on a central atom](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/finding-the-number-of-orbitals-on-a-central-atom)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Heating copper wire and sulfur powder](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/heating-copper-wire-and-sulfur-powder)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [What is the role of hydrochloric acid in a copper electroplating bath?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6473/what-is-the-role-of-hydrochloric-acid-in-a-copper-electroplating-bath)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

Comment: Pretty balanced, but not too promising. Too many homeworky ones, though many had a good amount of conceptualness. Still, I'd like some higher level activity (so I may have been stingy with votes this time)

Answer (score 6):

This set of review questions was in my opinion a bit weak.  There were very few questions with more than one answer, and while I didn't keep good track of the answers, I believe most of them were not accepted.

Homework questions seem to be on the rise and there may be a need to be a bit more critical of  the OPs who are posting these questions.

Comment: Physics is tightening up its treatment of HW. We already were a bit loose with it, maybe we should be a bit stricter? I'm not too sure on this. (When I get the time I'll flip through the HW questions we have and have a closer look at their quality)

Comment: @ManishEarth I was thinking of proposing a [tag:tutorial] which we could use in connection with homework.  For example, a Q might be "How do you solve concentration (molarity/molality) questions" and the answers provide a number of strategies, examples and references.  We could then mark generic homework questions as duplicates if they can be readily answered with the information in the tutorial Q&A.

Comment: Ah, basically a [tag:faq] question. Great idea!! Go ahead if you want; a meta post is good but not necessary here. If you feel we get the same type of question over and over again -- one that can be really addressed in a single self-answered/community wiki post, go ahead and write one and tag it as `[faq]`.